# Query Hunt Groups with TAPI and Avaya IP Office

Tags: telephony, tapi, pbx, avaya

I am using TAPI 2.X to develop a solution for Avaya IP Office 500 v2 PBX as 3th party application to control it. Right know I can make calls, hangup, intrude, open lines and so on. I need to query witch lines are acting as a queue because I have the default queue (200, Main in IPO are called Hunt Group) but in TAPI is shown as another line with a single  device connected to it. Can anyone give some hint or show me some kind of option to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Avaya TSP does that, but the standard way is to set LINEADDRCAPFLAGS_QUEUE bit in the dwAddrCapFlags field of the LINEADDRESSCAPS structure:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you're using our AddTapi dll you can check TapiAddress.IsQueue and TapiAddress.IsRoutePoint properties.